# Record Deletion from django model

Tags: python, django, model

if I have a live application with thousands of users in this scenario how I delete a record from Django model on live server ??? without effecting ??

first I reverse the migration then delete the record and makemigrations I try thin in local machine code and after changing I push the changes on server

Comment: What do you mean by record? Is it a field of a model ? Or just an entry  of your model ?

Comment: Really depends on the record you're talking about. You'll need to be more specific please.

Comment: yes I am talking about field like in user model how I delete user name ???